# How to add new users to watch-list in Redmine

Tags: redmine, bug-tracking, bug-tracker

How do I add new users to the "Watch List" for a particular bug in [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) so that they will get updates for changes to said bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in the process of creating a bug, you can scroll down to the bottom of the "New Issue" section, and select the watchers there.  This method will also ensure they are emailed about the creation of the bug.  IIRC, adding them after the fact doesn't result in their being emailed until an actual change is made to the bug's status.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that's the "easy way" to do it :-)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so this is a case of "the best to place to hide is in plain sight."

To add a user, open the bug and in the bottom right there will be a section called `Watchers`.  Next to that is an `Add` link.  Click that, and select the users to add to the watch list.  Screenshots below.

[image: Location of add link]
[image: Add Watchers dialog]